# Install Scilab on MacOs sierra

Tags: macos-sierra, scilab

I've just updated my MacOs into MacOs High Sierra and then Scilab 6.0.0 doesn't work anymore, by unmatching with the system version. How can I fix this problem or does it exist an intermediary software or alias (like anaconda) to use scilab on mac?
Thanks

Comment: In Scilab User's mailing list, it said that this is a problem related to libBLAS. This workaround http://mailinglists.scilab.org/Scilab-users-macOS-Sierra-Scilab-not-working-yet-tp4034586p4035093.html might work for you.

Comment: I cannot find the beta version anymore however I tried the code suggested for scilab 6.0.0 and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. From what I've read Scilab 6 is not compatible with Sierra. Scilab version 5.2.2 can be made to run under Sierra and there are instructions online to do this. I haven't tried it yet so can't vouch for it.